# Groovy code to read file and print Nth line after matching pattern

Tags: groovy

## Requirements

I need my script to do the following:

1. Read from a file ( see sample below )
2. Find an occurrence a line containing "Number 3"
3. Print the line that appears two lines below the aforementioned line

## Sample File Data

```
Line Number 1  
Line Number 2  
Line Number 3  
Line Number 4  
Line Number 5   
Line Number 6
```

## Expected Output

```
Line Number 5
```

## Code

I have the following code but do not know how to finish it

```
def file = new File('read.txt')
def data = file.eachLine { line, index ->
    if(line.contains('Number 3')){
        line_index = index+2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the `collect` closure to collect the lines into an array. Then use `findIndexOf` to find the index of the line containing your constant.  Then you simply increment the index by 2.

```
def lines = new File('\\read.txt').collect{it}
def index = lines.findIndexOf{ it ==~ /.*Number 3.*/ }

println lines[index+2]
```

> You can also use the `readLines()` method instead of the `collect{}` closure

If you want a more procedural and less functional solution more similar to your example, you can use use a loop and `readLines()` after finding the index

```
def file = new File('\\read.txt')
def lineIndex = -1
def constant = 'Number 3'


file.eachLine { line, index ->
    if(line.contains(constant)){
        lineIndex = index + 1
    }
}

println file.readLines()[lineIndex]
```

> Keep in mind, the second solution is incorrect if constant occurs on more than one line.  This first solution is preferable

Comment: Thanks Chris, We just need first occurrence of the string match. So, I think this should solve my problem. Thank you for helping me.